# How to safely execute custom statements within JOOQ's `ExecuteListener`?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jooq

I have a custom `ExecuteListener` that executes additional statements before the statement JOOQ is currently looking at:

```java
@Override
public void executeStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.type() != READ) {
        Timestamp nowTimestamp = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
        UUID user = auditFields.currentUserId(); // NOT the Postgres user!

        Connection conn = ctx.connection();
        try (Statement auditUserStmt = conn.createStatement();
             Statement auditTimestampStmt = conn.createStatement()) {

            // hand down context variables to Postgres via SET LOCAL:
            auditUserStmt.execute(format("SET LOCAL audit.AUDIT_USER = '%s'", user.toString()));
            auditTimestampStmt.execute(format("SET LOCAL audit.AUDIT_TIMESTAMP = '%s'", nowTimestamp.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to provide some DB-Triggers for auditing with context information. The trigger code is given below [1] to give you an idea. Note the `try-with-resources` that closes the two additional `Statement`s after execution.

This code works fine in the application server, where we use JOOQ's `DefaultConnectionProvider` and ordinary JOOQ queries (using the DSL), no raw text queries.

However, in the migration code, which uses a `DataSourceConnectionProvider`, the connection is already closed when JOOQ attempts to execute its INSERT/UPDATE query.

The INSERT that triggers the exception looks like this:

```java
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO migration.migration_journal (id, type, state) values ('%s', 'IDD', 'SUCCESS')", UUID.randomUUID());
dslContext.execute(sql);
```

and this is the exception raised:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.my.project.data.exception.RepositoryException: SQL [INSERT INTO migration.migration_journal (id, type, state) values ('09eea5ed-6a68-44bb-9888-195e22ade90d', 'IDD', 'SUCCESS')]; This statement has been closed.
        at com.my.project.shared.data.JOOQAbstractRepository.executeWithoutResult(JOOQAbstractRepository.java:51)
        at com.my.project.demo.data.migration.JooqMigrationJournalRepositoryUtil.addIDDJournalSuccessEntry(JooqMigrationJournalRepositoryUtil.java:10)
        at com.my.project.demo.data.demodata.DemoDbInitializer.execute(DemoDbInitializer.java:46)
        at com.my.project.shared.data.dbinit.AbstractDbInitializer.execute(AbstractDbInitializer.java:41)
        at com.my.project.demo.data.demodata.DemoDbInitializer.main(DemoDbInitializer.java:51)
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [INSERT INTO migration.migration_journal (id, type, state) values ('09eea5ed-6a68-44bb-9888-195e22ade90d', 'IDD', 'SUCCESS')]; This statement has been closed.
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:1690)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:660)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:354)
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.execute(DefaultDSLContext.java:736)
        at com.my.project.demo.data.migration.JooqMigrationJournalRepositoryUtil.lambda$addIDDJournalSuccessEntry$0(JooqMigrationJournalRepositoryUtil.java:12)
        at com.my.project.shared.data.JOOQAbstractRepository.executeWithoutResult(JOOQAbstractRepository.java:49)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkClosed(PgStatement.java:647)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:163)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:194)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:408)
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:340)
        ... 7 more
```

I traced this back to `DataSourceConnectionProvider.release()` and therefore `connection.close()` being called via `auditUserStmt.close()`. Note that it is critical that the `SET` commands are executed on the same `Connection`. I would be fine with obtaining a Statement from JOOQ's connection that I have to close myself, but I can't find a JOOQ method to obtain such an "unmanaged" statement.

We're using the Hikari connection pool, so the connection acquired by JOOQ is a `HikariProxyConnection`. From within the migration code, the `DataSource` is configured only minimally:

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
dataSource.setPoolName(poolName);
dataSource.setJdbcUrl(serverUrl);
dataSource.setUsername(user);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
```

How can I fix my `ExecuteListener`?

**I am using JOOQ 3.7.3 and Postgres 9.5., with the Postgres JDBC Driver 42.1.1.**

[1]: Postgres Trigger Code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_audit_fields()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  audit_user UUID;
BEGIN
  -- Postgres 9.6 will offer current_setting(..., [missing_ok]) which makes the exception handling obsolete.
  BEGIN
    audit_user := current_setting('audit.AUDIT_USER');
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    audit_user := NULL;
  END;

  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
  THEN
    NEW.inserted_by := audit_user;
  ELSE
    NEW.updated_by  := audit_user;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: 1) What's the JDBC driver version? 2) What made you implement this in `ExecuteListener`, rather than in your own `DataSource` proxy? In the latter case, you'll be in full control of *all* JDBC connections, not just of statements that run through jOOQ. 3) You mention that this only happens when a `DataSource` is involved. How did you configure your `DataSource`?

Comment: @LukasEder 1) That'd be postgresql-42.1.1. 2) Given that we use JOOQ to execute all statements, it seemed like the obvious place to inject this behaviour. I only need to execute the `SET LOCAL` statements for writing queries. If possible, I'd like to avoid to execute 2 additional statements for every `SELECT` statement and the `ExecuteListener` lets me check this conveniently without pulling regex tricks. 3) edited question.

Comment: Regarding 2) I see, well, you never know if you're going to run some other tool - e.g. Flyway :) Another reason why the `ExecuteListener` might not be the ideal place is the fact that you're now doing the `SET` calls on a per-statement level, rather than on a per-transaction level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @LukasEder's suggestion, I ended up solving this problem with a wrapper around the JDBC `Connection` instead of with an `ExecuteListener`.

The main complication in this approach is that JDBC does not provide anything to track the transaction status, and therefore the connection wrapper needs to re-set the context information every time the transaction was committed or rollbacked.

I documented my full solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/stellingsimon/f09005f666b01f2560d73f9e603b2a97), since it's too long to fit in an SO answer.