# Execute a query inside JOOQ ExecuteListener when not in transaction

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I'm trying to set some transaction variables before each DML call in JOOQ. To do this I added the following code:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TriggerEnablerExecuteListener extends DefaultExecuteListener implements ExecuteListenerProvider {

    @Override
    public void executeStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.type() == ExecuteType.WRITE) {
            DSLContext db = new DefaultDSLContext(ctx.connection(), POSTGRES);
            db.execute("SET LOCAL enable_trigger = 'true'");            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExecuteListener provide() {
        // Stateless listener
        return this;
    }
}
```

This works well, but only when the query is executed inside a transaction. When not running in a transaction this fails with exception:

```
DataAccessException: SQL [SET LOCAL enable_trigger = 'true']; PooledConnection has already been closed.
```

I realise SET LOCAL does not work when not in transaction, and that in general it is a bad practice to not run in transaction, but I still did not expect to fail here. Running the same queries in postgres will only generate a warning.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416149/how-to-safely-execute-custom-statements-within-jooqs-executelistener) but I believe this is a simpler use case, since I'm using the regular JOOQ connection provider.

Versions

Jooq - 3.10.8; PG - 10.13; JDBC driver - 9.4.1212.jre7; Spring Boot - 1.5.21

Comment: I don't think that this hase something to do with transaction. The error message says that  connection is closed. Is there an exception before this call happens?

Comment: And the point from the other question applies also here: When using an ExecuteListenerProvider this will happen with every statement but should be done only once per transaction

Comment: Problem is I need some spring beans (it's not in the code example, but the real code takes the trigger value from some feature toggle service) so I can't use the code sample in the answer. Also it is old version and I was hoping there is some better workaround today.

Comment: There was no exception before the call happened. I couldn't find a way to plug something in the beginning of transaction. Also, since most transaction are doing mostly reads, I will make redundant calls, so this is actually more efficient (I can make it even more efficient by persisting the fact that I made the call on thread local, and releasing this in the end of transaction - for this I can actually plug a spring event to do this)

Comment: You could also use AOP

Comment: @SimonMartinelli AOP is a last resort.. are we allowed to edit the statement in the context? Maybe I can just paste my query inside.

Comment: Could be a bug related to combining jOOQ with Spring Boot and e.g. Hikari. Can you report it here https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new, possibly with an MCVE that helps reproducing it? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve